# $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous surjection, $X$ and $Y$ are topological space

Tags: general-topology

$f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous surjection Then

1. If $V$ is open, does this imply $f(V)$ is open?
2. If $F$ is closed, does this imply $f(F)$ is closed?
3. If $A$ is an infinite subset, does this imply that $f(A)$ is so in $Y$?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of these is true.

Let $\Bbb S$ be the [Sierpiński space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space), i.e. $\Bbb S=\{0,1\}$ where the open sets are $\emptyset,\{1\}$ and $\{0,1\}$.

Define $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb S$ as follows: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0;&x\leq 0\\1;&x>0\end{cases}$$

This is a continuous surjection, since $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is open, but none of the properties holds:

- $f((-\infty,0))=\{0\}$ is not open
- $f([1,\infty))=\{1\}$ is not closed
- the image of $\Bbb R$ is finite.

Comment: could you check once more about $f$?

Comment: Point 2 seems false, since $f(0) = 0$. $f([1,\infty))=\{1\}$, though.

Comment: @Arthur: Thanks, modified it. It should be ok now.

Comment: @Dejan, you need to redefine $f$ I think typo.

Comment: @DejanGovc Now its ok!

Comment: beautiful construction! how did that came into your mind?

Comment: @TaxiDriver: thanks. Well, $\mathbb S$ is one of the spaces I really like to think about (and seemed appropriate) so I just had to try it. =)

Answer (score 4):

1 is false. Consider $f(x) = |x| \sin x$, then $f((-\pi, \pi)) = [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.

Answer (score 4):

All three are false.

1. $X=I$, $Y=S^1$ and $f$ glues the ends of $I$ together. Then any open subset $(a,1]\subseteq I$ is mapped to a non-open set.
2. Let $X=Y$ as sets, where $X$ has the discret and $Y$ has the trivial topology. Any subset of $X$ is closed but not necessarily in $Y$.
3. $X=Y\coprod Y$ with $Y$ infinite and $f$ the identity on one component and constant on the other one.

Answer (score 3):

$3$ is false as you can construct functions that are locally constant and choose $X$ disconnected (each connected component infinite) for a counterexample.

Comment: Let $X=(0,1)\cup (2,3)$ in usual subspace topology, then locally constant functions are surjective? what about $1,2$

Comment: Let $Y$ be the two point set with any topology! They will be because the inverse image of each point is either $(0,1)$ or $(2,3)$. So continuity holds. So does surjectivity!

Comment: okay got it :))

Answer (score 2):

1 and 2 are false. Here are counterexamples for them:

1. Let $X= [0,1)$ with the subspace topology and let $Y = S^1$ with the subspace topology. Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be the map defined by 
   $$f(t) = (\cos 2 \pi t, \sin 2\pi t).$$
   Then it is easy to see that not only is $f$ continuous, but that it is also bijective and hence surjective. I claim that $f$ is not an open map. Look at $V = [0,\frac{1}{4})$ that is open in $X$. Then we see that there is no $U$ open in $\Bbb{R}^2$ such that $f(0) \in U \cap S^{1} \subseteq f(V)$. It follows that $f$ is not open.
2. Consider $\Bbb{R}$ with the Euclidean topology. Let $\Bbb{R}/\sim$ be the quotient space obtained by saying that $x \sim y$ iff $ x -y \in \Bbb{Q}$. Then it is not hard to see that the quotient topology on $\Bbb{R}/\sim$ is trivial. Furthermore $\Bbb{R}/\sim$ is uncountable. Now let $\pi $ be the canonical projection of $\Bbb{R}$ onto the quotient. Then $\Bbb{Z}$ is closed in $\Bbb{R}$ but $\pi(\Bbb{Z}) = [0]$ that is not closed in $\Bbb{R}/\sim$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two definitions which may be helpful for you:

> If $1$ is true, we call $f$ is an open function; If $2$ is true, we call $f$ is a closed function. All these functions are different from continuous functions.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement is true if $f$ is an open map.
The second statement is true if $f$ is a closed map.